# Handling a success in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am experimenting with t library, and am trying to install the functionality into my own search bar to practice (still a student).

Can anyone provide advice to the format this would be in??

Comment: Place the `wappalyzer.open()` method *inside* the `then()`. Alternatively, chain the then() calls: https://javascript.info/promise-chaining

Comment: @ZAR Does that handle the success? Not sure what that would do....

Comment: so the first call to init returns a success on init, which is when you want wappalyzer to open the uri. You'll also want the res.json to be within the then() method too.  Quick Q, are you specificially trying to do this with promise chaining instead of using `await`?

Comment: @ZAR no particular reason I am using promise chaining instead of await.

Comment: @ZAR can you please provide an answer as to what this would look like? visual learner...

Comment: fetch call should be to localhost with specific GET param, like `fetch('http://localhost:8080/google.com')`

Answer (score 3):

Completely ignoring what `wappalyzer` actually is or does, I would suggest the following, since you are already providing an `async` function as callback to your route controller :

```js
app.get('/:url', async function (req, res) {
  
  try {

    await wappalyzer.init();
    const site = await wappalyzer.open(decodeURIComponent(req.query.url));
    const data = await site.analyze();

    // if you end up here, everything was successfull
    return res.status(200).json(data);

  } catch (ex) {
    
    // if you end up here, something went wrong
    return res.status(500).json({ message : ex.message });

  }

});
```

The above doesn't really make much sense, since you are telling your backend to look for an `url` param but using a query parameter instead. I woudln't recommend to send an `url` as either, param or query. Use the request `body` instead :

```js
// receive request in backend, with an endpoint that makes a bit more sense
// also using POST method, otherwise you won't be able to send a body
app.post('/search', async function (req, res) {
  const url = req.body.url;
  // do stuff
});

// sending request to backend, using axios for example
const respond = await axios.post('/search', { url : 'www.google.com' });

// or using fetch
const respond = await fetch('/search', {
  method: 'post',
  body: JSON.stringify({ url : 'www.google.com' });
```

Please be aware these are just pointers, nothing to copy & paste :) .

If you are using Express, I suggest reading the documentation again. I think you are misunderstanding how the router works : https://expressjs.com/de/guide/routing.html#route-parameters

Comment: Beat me to it. Using await is the cleanest way to go about this.

Comment: @pascallamers Thank you so much!! I got an error 500 when loading the webpage, but will have to do some investigation into why this is (unless you have an idea why). Thanks!

Comment: @KirtMac99 when you say you got a 500, from the `wappalyzer.open()` call or from calling your backend API? If the former, can you send the value of req.query.url?

Comment: It probably means there was error within the try catch block. Try logging the error to console to see whats going on .

Comment: Ah - looking at the route again you are routing for a param ':url' - these are stored in req.params not req.query. How does the url look that you trying to request here ?

Comment: @PascalLamers I adjusted to Params, and still no luck. 

When I input a URL into the search bar on the client-side, and search, the URL itself does not change and just stays at my local host instead of displaying results.

However, when I insert  /:url into the local host url I get the error message displaying on screen

Note: I am using express

Comment: You are sending a GET request from your client side app to your express  backend : how does this request look like ?

Comment: @KirtMac99 in addition to Pascal's Q, can you also describe the intended functionality?

Comment: @PascalLamers I was told not to use a get request, but to use a fetch on CS, as they can be used interchangeably. Here is the script tag on client-side:

const form = document.querySelector("form");
      function processForm(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
        const formResult = new FormData(form); 
        const URL = encodeURIComponent(formResult.get("search")); 
     
        fetch("/:url").then(res => res.text()).then(result => console.log(result)); 
          }
        form.addEventListener("submit", processForm);

Comment: Please update your Question with these additional information, thanks !

Comment: @ZAR I want to be able to search a domain on my front end, and retrieve the results from wappalyzer using the NPM package. Apologies if these are basic questions... still learning some things.

Comment: I updated my answer with some suggestions and pointers

Comment: @KirtMac99 glad I could help ! Please accept answer if correct

Answer (score 3):

[@PascalLamers answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65469615/2942295) is the cleanest way to go about it, using the "await" pattern.

To see what this looks like with promise chaining:

```
app.get('/:url', async function (req, res) {

  return wappalyzer
    .init()
    .then(function(){
       return wappalyzer.open(decodeURIComponent(req.params.url))
    })
    .then(function(site){
       return site.analyze()
    })
    .then(function(data){
       return res.status(200).json(data);
    })
    .catch(function(err){
      return res.status(500).json({ message : err.message })
    })
}
```

Each then executes a single async operation, and on success passes its result to the next `then()` operation.

Each `then()` is only called upon the success of the previous `then()`. If an error occurs at any point, the `catch()` is executed and the function returns (in this case, returns an error 500).